# Dúvida sobre camadas necessárias num Gateway simples feito em STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um web serviçe json/rest que faz o papel de um gateway, o cliente manda a requisição para um endpoint, mas o gateway replica o request para vários serviços. Nele, apenas repasso o request e junto o response no momento de devolver. Minha dúvida é: preciso colocar neste gateway todas as camadas que já existem nos serviços?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não entendi bem por que você quer colocar serviços num gateway, que basicamente é responsável por direcionar requests apenas. Tudo o que seu gateway precisa é do endereço do microsserviço pra onde ele precisa direcionar a requisição.

Comment: OK! Então não vai ser preciso colocar as camadas extrar, basta redirecionar e pronto, né isso?
A propósito da pergunta: o cliente não quer acessar vários endponts para receber informações semelhantes, solicitou apenas um lugar para coletar as informações, como as origens eram distintas, as empresas envolvidas fizeram cada um seu serviço e então unifiquei tudo como gateway.
Responde a pergunta para eu apontar como solução ;-) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Não, não coloque objetos de negócio dentro de um gateway. Mantenha seu acoplamento o mais fraco possível.

---

**Explicação**

Um gateway não deve conhecer o core do negócio.

Sendo assim, não, você não deve inserir objetos de negócio na camada do gateway.  Isso ajuda a preservar o baixo (ou quase nulo) acoplamento.
Assim, o gateway faz apenas o papel simplório de um 'passthrough'.

Claro, existem gateways e gateways. Hoje em dia os API Gateways fazem muito mais que isso. São capazes de fazer segurança e, em muitos, até orquestração e enriquecimento de mensagens - se isso é certo ou errado não vem ao caso do tópico, mas, minha opinião é de que o gateway não deve ser utilizado nunca para fazer orquestrações e enriquecimentos, ele deve apenas fazer uma camada de segurança e o roteamento para o back-end destino.

Se você está utilizando Spring, seria interessante dar uma olhada na stack Spring Cloud. Há o [Zuul API Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#router-and-filter-zuul). Ele faria esse papel que você implementou absolutamente bem e tem uma facilidade imensa de configuração.

Ele é um projeto Java como qualquer outro, com as bibliotecas importadas através do Maven ou Gradle, porém, você apenas o configura utilizando um arquivo YAML e pronto! Seu gateway está funcionando